# How to make advanced url routings in flask?

Tags: python, flask

this is my code:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/<type>")
@app.route('/page/<int:page>')
def index(type="top", page=0):
    perpage=5
    startat=page*perpage
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    if type=='top':
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT %s, %s", (startat,perpage))
        data = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return render_template("index.html", dat=data)
    elif type=='new':
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT %s, %s", (startat,perpage))
        data = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return render_template("index.html", dat=data)
```

I am trying to make **pagination** along the **order by** work together without problem:

- `/page/1` works
- but `/new/page/1` is not working

So how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a bad urls architecture: There are two similar  urls: `@app.route("/page")` and `@app.route("/<type>")` because `type` is a string variable and can be assigned to `page` value.

Anyway, to solve your problem, you need to create a non-confusing urls. For example:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/page/<type>/")
@app.route('/page/<type>/<int:page>')
def index(type="top", page=0):
    perpage=5
    #...
```

In this case, `type` can't be assigned to empty string as default value.

Other possible solution:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/some-text/<type>")
@app.route('/page/<int:page>')
def index(type="top", page=0):
    perpage=5
```

Comment: that didn't work but you gave me an idea: `@app.route("/")
@app.route("/<type>/")
@app.route('/<type>/page/<int:page>')
def index(type="top", page=0):`  ye3tik sahha Taher شكرا من الجزائر

Comment: Anytime, glad it helped. A7la nass, mar7ba b 5awitna f Algérie.